# Rust error handling - capturing multiple errors

Tags: rust, error-handling

I've started to learn Rust last week, by reading books and articles, and trying to convert some code from other languages at the same time.

I came across a situation which I'm trying to exemplify through the code below (which is a simplified version of what I was trying to convert from another language):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct InvalidStringSize;
impl std::fmt::Display for InvalidStringSize {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "string is too short")
    }
}
impl std::error::Error for InvalidStringSize {}

pub fn extract_codes_as_ints(
    message: String,
) -> Result<(i32, i32, i32), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    if message.len() < 20 {
        return Err(Box::new(InvalidStringSize {}));
    }
    let code1: i32 = message[0..3].trim().parse()?;
    let code2: i32 = message[9..14].trim().parse()?;
    let code3: i32 = message[17..20].trim().parse()?;
    Ok((code1, code2, code3))
}
```

So basically I want to extract 3 integers from specific positions of the given string (I could also try to check the other characters for some patterns, but I've left that part out).

I was wondering, is there a way to "catch" or verify all three results of the parse calls at the same time? I don't want to add a match block for each, I'd just like to check if anyone resulted in an error, and return another error in that case. Makes sense?

The only solution I could think of so far would be to create another function with all parses, and match its result. Is there any other way to do this?

Also, any feedback/suggestions on other parts of the code is very welcome, I'm struggling to find out the "right way" to do things in Rust.

Comment: I don't really grasp what you want: you already err when a number isn't parseable, don't you?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman My understanding is that OP wants to catch the parse error and return a different type error in that case.

Comment: Yes, exactly as @Lagerbaer said, sorry if I didn’t make myself clear. Another possibility would be to add some error handling code too, like logging or whatnot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic way to accomplish this is to define your own error type and return it, with a `From<T>` implementation for each error type `T` that can occur in your function. The `?` operator will use `From` conversions to match the error type your function is declared to return.

A boxed error is overkill here; just declare an enum listing all of the ways the function can fail.  The variant for an integer parse error can even capture the caught error.

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Error as FmtError};
use std::num::ParseIntError;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum ExtractCodeError {
    InvalidStringSize,
    InvalidInteger(ParseIntError),
}

impl From<ParseIntError> for ExtractCodeError {
    fn from(e: ParseIntError) -> Self {
        Self::InvalidInteger(e)
    }
}

impl Error for ExtractCodeError {}

impl Display for ExtractCodeError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), FmtError> {
        match self {
            Self::InvalidStringSize => write!(f, "string is too short"),
            Self::InvalidInteger(e) => write!(f, "invalid integer: {}", e)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Aside: if you use the [`thiserror`](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/) crate to derive `Error`, this code becomes way simpler:

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, thiserror::Error)]
pub enum ExtractCodeError {
    #[error("string is too short")]
    InvalidStringSize,
    #[error("invalid integer: {0}")]
    InvalidInteger(#[from] ParseIntError),
}
```

---

Now we just need to change your function's return type and have it return `ExtractCodeError::InvalidStringSize` when the length is too short.  Nothing else needs to change as a `ParseIntError` is automatically converted into an `ExtractCodeError`:

```
pub fn extract_codes_as_ints(
    message: String,
) -> Result<(i32, i32, i32), ExtractCodeError> {
    if message.len() < 20 {
        return Err(ExtractCodeError::InvalidStringSize);
    }
    let code1: i32 = message[0..3].trim().parse()?;
    let code2: i32 = message[9..14].trim().parse()?;
    let code3: i32 = message[17..20].trim().parse()?;
    Ok((code1, code2, code3))
}
```

As an added bonus, callers of this function will be able to inspect errors more easily than with a boxed `dyn Error`.

In more complex cases, such as where you'd want to tweak the error slightly for each possible occurrence of a `ParseIntError`, you can use `.map_err()` on results to transform the error.  For example:

```
something_that_can_fail.map_err(|e| SomeOtherError::Foo(e))?;
```

Comment: That was very insightful! Thanks!